# Django send_mass_email with html content

Tags: python, html, django

Im triying to send a mass email with django's "send_mass_email" method, i've read the documentation but the examples only show plain text messages.

How can i be able to send HTML messages with the "send_mass_emal" method? i tried like a regular email but the recived only html code. Here is my code:

```
                    for row_index in range(12, sheet.nrows):
                    if sheet.cell(rowx=row_index, colx=0).value != "":
                        template = get_template("MonthlyEmail.html")
                        context = Context({
                            'name': str(clean_string(sheet.cell(rowx=row_index, colx=2).value)),
                            'doc_type': str(sheet.cell(rowx=row_index, colx=4).value),
                            'document': str(sheet.cell(rowx=row_index, colx=3).value),
                            'email': str(sheet.cell(rowx=row_index, colx=5).value),
                            'acc_numb': str(sheet.cell(rowx=row_index, colx=6).value),
                            'brute_salary': str(sheet.cell(rowx=row_index, colx=8).value),
                            'vacation_commision': str(sheet.cell(rowx=row_index, colx=9).value),
                            'brute_total': str(sheet.cell(rowx=row_index, colx=10).value),
                            'social_sec': str(sheet.cell(rowx=row_index, colx=14).value),
                            'isr': str(sheet.cell(rowx=row_index, colx=27).value),
                            'other_retention': str(sheet.cell(rowx=row_index, colx=13).value),
                            'net_payment': str(sheet.cell(rowx=row_index, colx=29).value)
                        })
                        content = template.render(context)

                        messages.append(('Monthly Salary Report', content,
                                                     'intranet@intranet.com',
                                                     [str(sheet.cell(rowx=row_index, colx=5).value)]))


                send_mass_mail_html(messages, fail_silently=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like `send_mass_email()` supports HTML emails. But there is a way to do it by taking inspiration [from the code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/core/mail/#send_mail) of Django's `send_mail()` function:

```
connection = connection or get_connection(
    username=auth_user,
    password=auth_password,
    fail_silently=fail_silently,
)
mail = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, connection=connection)
if html_message:
    mail.attach_alternative(html_message, 'text/html')

mail.send()
```

The general strategy seems to create a connection first, then for each email you need to send, create an instance of `EmailMultiAlternatives`, passing it the existing connection, then send it, exactly as `send_mail` but in a loop...

Answer (score 1):

I have wrote my own functionality to use mass email by using the django documentaion as reference.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import render_to_string


def get_rendered_html(template_name, context={}):
    html_content = render_to_string(template_name, context)
    return html_content


def send_email(subject, html_content, text_content=None, from_email=None, recipients=[], attachments=[], bcc=[], cc=[]):
    # send email to user with attachment
    if not from_email:
        from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
    if not text_content:
        text_content = ''
    email = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        subject, text_content, from_email, recipients, bcc=bcc, cc=cc
    )
    email.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    for attachment in attachments:
        # Example: email.attach('design.png', img_data, 'image/png')
        email.attach(*attachment)
    email.send()


def send_mass_mail(data_list):
    for data in data_list:
        template = data.pop('template')
        context = data.pop('context')
        html_content = get_rendered_html(template, context)
        data.update({'html_content': html_content})
        send_email(**data)


message1 = {
    'subject': 'Subject here',
    'text_content': 'Here is the message',
    'from_email': 'from@example.com',
    'recipients': ['first@example.com', 'other@example.com'],
    'template': "template1.html",
    'context': {"d1": "mydata"}
}

message2 = {
    'subject': 'Subject here',
    'text_content': 'Here is the message',
    'from_email': 'from@example.com',
    'recipients': ['first@example.com', 'other@example.com'],
    'template': "template2.html",
    'context': {"d2": "mydata"}
}

send_mass_mail([message1, message2])
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/core/mail/#send_mass_mail

Answer (score 0):

I wrote custom mass mail method and it is working fine:-

```
from django.core.mail.message import EmailMessage
from django.core.mail import get_connection

def send_custom_mass_mail(datatuple, fail_silently=False, auth_user=None,
                   auth_password=None, connection=None):
    """
    coloned fromt he core
    """
    connection = connection or get_connection(
        username=auth_user,
        password=auth_password,
        fail_silently=fail_silently,
    )
    EmailMessage.content_subtype = 'html'
    messages = [
        EmailMessage(subject, message, sender, recipient, connection=connection)
        for subject, message, sender, recipient in datatuple
    ]
    return connection.send_messages(messages)
```

Then I use as per [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#send-mass-mail):

```
send_custom_mass_mail((mail_to_lead), fail_silently=False)
```